# how to create AWS managed KMS Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

How to create a AWS managed KEY .

[image]

How can I create AWS managed keys. as shown in the picture attached . I understand KMS and how to create symmetric and Asymetric keys . but I am not able to understand this AWS managed keys and from where we can create these .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I create AWS managed keys.

You **can't create them explicitly**. AWS creates them for you (thus they are AWS managed) when needed.

So lets say that you will create EBS volume with encryption. When you do this, AWS will create AWS managed key for you automatically. Only then you will be able to see it in KMS console.

Comment: got it . thanks . we want to use lambda and KMS to encrypt data and save it to the underlying database . so I think I need to use customer managed key  and create symmetric key as per our use case. please confirm . AWS managed keys won't work /show up with lambda  .

Comment: @divyanayanawasthi Yes, you need customer key. AWS managed keys are only for AWS services, such as S3, EBS, dynamodb, etc. You can't use them to encrypt random data.